# Data driven testing in selenium ide using data base

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide, data-driven-tests

I want to write test cases in selenium ide which can take the data directly from database.Means I want to do data driven testing using all the data store in my database.Test cases could get the data directly from data base rather than getting from a xml file.

Comment: Hard to do in Selenium IDE, doable in Selenium Webdriver. Have look at Webdriver references, because there you could do that

Comment: IDE is written in javascript. Not really meant for connecting to the DB. Maybe easier if there was an API laid on top of the DB. Otherwise I think this is something you'd want to turn to webdriver for as Pavel said.